# Let $A \in SO(3)$ show that $1$ is always an eigenvalue. (Proof check and alternative proof?)

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, linear-transformations, alternative-proof, rotations

Given $A \in SO(3)$ show that $1$ is always an eigenvalue. Where $SO(3)$ is the 3-dimensional special orthogonal group.

This is an exercise from Lie Groups and Algebras with Applications to Physics, Geometry, and Mechanics.

Intuitively it seems obvious. If I think of a rotating cilinder about some axis of rotation, then the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ would be a some vector on the axis of rotation.

The proof I found however, is more algebraic.

Can I get a proof check?

And is there a more intuistionictic proof? Or is the algebraic proof a result of the algebraic definition I used for $SO(3)$?

By definition of $SO(3)$ we have that the entries of $A$ are real, $A^T = A^{-1}$ and that $\text{det}(A) = 1$.

Lemma 1: the eigenvalues of $A$ are either $1$ or $-1$.

Proof:
$$\langle v,v \rangle = \langle v,I v \rangle 
      = \langle v,A^{-1}Av \rangle
      = \langle v,A^{T}Av \rangle  
      = \langle {A^{T}}^T v,Av \rangle  
      = \langle  Av,Av \rangle
      =\langle  \lambda v, \lambda v \rangle
      = \lambda^2 \langle  v, v \rangle
      $$
So $\lambda^2 = 1$, so $\lambda$ is either $1$ or $-1$. QED

Lemma 2: $\text{det}(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$.

Proof:
Let $v$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$Av = \lambda v$$
$$Av = \lambda I v$$
$$(A - \lambda I) v = 0.$$
Since, $v$ is non-zero, the matrix $A - \lambda I$ is non-invertible, which yields the characteristic equation:
$$\text{det}(A-\lambda I) = 0.$$
Since we already know that all eigenvalues are real, the characteristic equation splits in $R$:
$$\text{det}(A-\lambda I) = (\lambda_1 - \lambda)(\lambda_2 - \lambda)(\lambda_3 - \lambda).$$
Setting $\lambda = 0$ gives:
$$\text{det}(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3.$$ QED

For a contradiction, assume that all eigenvalues equal $-1$, then by lemma 2 we get $\text{det}(A) = -1$, which is a contradiction. So, at least one eigenvalue is not equal to $-1$. By lemma 1, this eigenvalue must be equal to 1. QED.

Comment: For your lemma 1, there can also be non-real complex eigenvalues (consider a $90^\circ$ rotation about the $z$ axis, with eigenvalues $1, i$ and $-i$).

Comment: @Arthur Where did it go wrong then? Because $\lambda^2 = 1$ doesn't admit complex solutions right?

Comment: @JensWagemaker The mistake is in assuming all eigenvalues are real, $\langle\lambda v,\lambda v\rangle=\lambda\bar\lambda\langle v,v\rangle\neq\lambda^2\langle v,v\rangle$ since the inner product preserved by $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ is sesquilinear rather than $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1127388/11619). Without the solution verification component, the question would be a duplicate. As I happened to answer that version back in the day I should not be the first to vote to close, I think. @user10354138's comment makes a perfect answer, as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, your Lemma 1 is wrong. However, your proof can be correct after slightly modified.

The correct statement of Lemma 1 is:

> Lemma 1: the REAL eigenvalues of $A$ are either 1 or −1.

and this can be proved using your method.

You have solved the problem when the characteristic equation $\mathrm{det}(A−λI)=0$ have 3 real roots. Otherwise, if the characteristic equation have one real root $a$ and a pair of complex roots $b\pm ci$, we can get
$$1 = \mathrm{det}(A) = a(b+ci)(b-ci) = a(b^2+c^2).$$
Thus $a=\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}$ is positive and can only be 1.